# Arrow keys as accesskeys?

Tags: html

Is it possible to use arrow keys as [access keys](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Access_key), as in <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>rightArrowKey</kbd> for a key combination?

Comment: What do you mean? From your own wikipedia link it doesn't suggest that you can, so I'd think not. But you can, of course, implement something in JavaScript (though that may not help, if your environment doesn't run JavaScript).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Says [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.11.2) that you have to specify a character as access key, and although you could try using [arrow ASCII codes](http://www.jguru.com/faq/view.jsp?EID=475275) in Unicode format as access key characters, I doubt that it's going to work. Better to use JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

will not work with html access keys, you must use Javascript.